# Need help translating matrix formula into Python code

Tags: python, math, matrix

I'm new to Python and I need some help translating the following formulas into Python code:

[image]

[image]

I am currently working it out with numpy but with little to no progress. Any reference materials will be well appreciated.

Comment: What does the second formula mean and what is it for? What is the iteration variable for the sum? And how is the absolute value of a set defined in this context?

Comment: @SvenKrüger Both formulas are to calculate distances between two variables in a given matrix. The iteration variable n would be the number of rows in the matrix. I'm not sure what you mean by defining the absolute value. Apologies for my lack

Comment: `n` is the last value of the iteration variable. In the first formula `t` is the iteration variable. What are `a_t`, `i`, `j`, `P_x` and `P_y` in the second formula?... The absolute value is indicated like this `| x |`. So what is the absolute value of a set?

Comment: @SvenKrüger For the second eqn, assume cluster infomation: row_i ∈ P_x and row_j ∈ P_y. |{a_t ∈ P_x ⋁ a_t ∈ P_y}| is the number of columns in the union of clusters P_x and P_y. I'm not sure but I believe the absolute value is derived from the matrix which values are provided from a database.

Comment: It is common to use the absolute value signs on a set to mean the size of the set. That makes perfect sense in this context: see the summation in the numerator. I am more concerned about the different meanings of `a` in the two formulas. In the first formula, `a` appears to be a constant index. In the second formula it appears to be a list or mapping, where `t` is the index or key. Are the `a`s really supposed to be different? Another question: do you want the code to use pure Python or should it use the numpy module?

Comment: @RoryDaulton sorry for the confusion here. In this case, the a and b from the first formula is similar to the i and j in the second formula, respectively. As n represents the matrix's rows, a in the second just represents the columns. As for your last question, which would you suggest to be more efficient? Thanks so much for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility. Some of the assumptions are in the comments. There are other ways to do this, of course. The size of the set in the denominator of the second formula could be done more simply as the length of a set or list, but my way avoids the memory usage of the set/list and is more consistent with the numerator.

```
def formula1(X, n, a, b):
    """Return the first formula for matrix X, size n, and indices a and b.
    """
    return sum(X[a][t] - X[b][t] for t in range(1, n+1)) / n

def formula2(X, n, i, j, x, y, a, P):
    """Return the second formula for matrix X, size n, indices i, j, x, and y,
    array or mapping a, array or mapping of sets P.
    """
    numer = sum(abs(X[i][t] - X[j][t])
                for t in range(1, n+1)
                if a[t] in P[x] or a[t] in P[y])
    denom = sum(1
                for t in range(1, n+1)
                if a[t] in P[x] or a[t] in P[y])
    return numer / denom
```